# Can I use MEF to compose several items of the same type with different constructor arguments?

Tags: c#, mef

I have the following interface defined

- `IOne`
- `ITwo`
- `IThree`
- `ICalcalculator`

And have several implementations of them

- `ClassOne: IOne`
- `ClassTwo: IOne`
- `ClassThree : ITwo`
- `ClassFour : ITwo`
- `ClassFive: IThree`
- `MyCalc : ICalculator`

MyCalc requires classes 1-4, however 2 instances of `ClassOne` and `ClassThree` differentiated as initialization i.e.

```
public MyCalc(){
    ClassOne first= new ClassOne("filePath1");
    ClassOne second = new ClassOne("filePath2");
    ClassThree third = new ClassThree ("filePath3");
    ClassThree fourth = new ClassThree ("filePath4");
}
```

I am trying to use MEF to create construct MyCalc. In the above example, the `filePathX` will be in a configuration file. I have done the following thus far and  it seems to work, however my feeling is that my current method and approach is not correct. Looking at this approach, I have bound myself with names (ValDatePrices & EDDatePrices) and it is no cleaner than my current approach(see above).

Is there a cleaner way to load several objects of the same type with different ctor arguments?

```
public class MyCalc: ICalculator
{
    private CompositionContainer container; 

    public MyCalc()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyCalc).Assembly));

        container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        try
        {

        this.container.ComposeExportedValue<ClassFive>(
               new ClassFive((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomePath"])));
        this.container.ComposeExportedValue<ClassOne>(
              "ValDatePrices"
              , new ClassOne((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath1"])));
        this.container.ComposeExportedValue<ClassOne>(
              "EDDatePrices"
               , new ClassOne((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath2"])));

        this.container.ComposeParts(this);

        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
        }

    }

    [Import("ValDatePrices")]
    public ClassOne ValDatePrices;

    [Import("EDDatePrices")]
    public ClassOne EDDatePrices;

    [Import]
    public ClassFive SPointReader;

    public void Calculate()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(SPointReader.Result);
        Console.WriteLine(ValDatePrices.Result.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(EDDatePrices.Result.Count);

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new MyCalc();
        p.Calculate();
    }
}
}
```

*Side question: where should the code in the `MyCalc` constructor be located?*

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a proper DI/IoC container? This can be easily achieved in a clean way using e.g. [NInject](http://ninject.org/) or [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/).

Here is an example of how this can be implemented with NInject. Note that there are numerous ways of doing this, you should look at their tutorial to get NInject to suit you needs.

**MyCalculator**

```
public class MyCalculator : ICalculator
{
    private IOne _oneFirst;
    private IOne _oneSecond;
    private ITwo _twoFirst;
    private ITwo _twoSecond;
    private IThree _three;


    public MyCalculator([Named("Val")] IOne oneFirst, [Named("ED")] IOne oneSecond,
                        [Named("Val")] ITwo twoFirst, [Named("ED")] ITwo twoSecond, IThree three)
    {
        _oneFirst = oneFirst;
        _oneSecond = oneSecond;
        _twoFirst = twoFirst;
        _twoSecond = twoSecond;
        _three = three;

    }

    public void Calculate()
    {

    }
}
```

**Kernel**

```
public class CalculatorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IOne>().ToMethod(CreateOne).Named("Val");
        Bind<IOne>().ToMethod(CreateTwo).Named("ED");
        Bind<ITwo>().ToMethod(CreateThree).Named("Val");
        Bind<ITwo>().ToMethod(CreateFour).Named("ED");
        Bind<IThree>().To<ClassFive>();
        Bind<ICalculator>().To<MyCalculator>();

    }

    private ITwo CreateFour(IContext arg)
    {
        return new ClassFour();
    }

    private ITwo CreateThree(IContext arg)
    {
        return new ClassThree();
    }

    private IOne CreateOne(IContext context)
    {
        return new ClassOne("filePath1");
    }

    private IOne CreateTwo(IContext arg)
    {
        return new ClassTwo("filePath2");
    }


}
```

*Note about kernel:* The methods can be shortened to lambda functions if you like and the named attributes can be replaced by parameter names or custom attributes. See [Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

**Usage**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new CalculatorModule());
        var cal = kernel.Get<ICalculator>();
        cal.Calculate();
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good, never thought about it like this before - tried it and works, looking for a MEF based solution though, since the ultimate goal is to encompass these ideas in a WPF/Prism based application

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use MEF? NInject can do all MEF can do and more, stuff like property imports/injections, multi-injection, etc. I'd say It's very compatible with WPF and in most cases a much better option than Prism. It's simple, yet powerful :)